# Searching for mathematical expressions

Tags: support, mathjax, search

I got this question a few years back in an postgrad interview and it had me stumped until the interviewer suggested the trick to it. I solved it again just now on paper and wanted to check my answer. I looked here for it using `[calculus] x^x` as the search term but couldn't find it.

Is this the right way to go about searching the site? I've never used the site to search for a mathematical expression so I thought maybe I'm not using the search properly because this is such a well-known problem.

If it really isn't present I'll add it as a question -- it's a classic problem and should be on our site despite having solutions available elsewhere.

Comment: related: [Search queries involving symbols and/or TEX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6180/search-queries-involving-symbols-and-or-tex) and [I can't search on ^](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/i-cant-search-on/7103#7103)

Comment: The site search isn't very good with such expressions, letting google search `calculus derivative "x^x" site:math.stackexchange.com` turns up [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339272/derivative-of-x-x-without-logarithmic-differentiation) (and several irrelevant results). In the "Related" list of that, there's also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696064/differentiating-y-xx-with-the-formal-definition-of-a-derivative?rq=1).

Comment: I've changed the title, because the original one suggested a question about "What is the derivative of $x^x$?" and not "How do I search mathematical expressions?". I've also added the [meta-tag:search] and [meta-tag:mathjax] to classify the question. Not sure if [meta-tag:mathjax] really fits so feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes. `[calculus] "x^x"` gives me a relevant thread in the first page of results.

Comment: thanks. I had pretty much got there already. But even as an experienced user of the site it's really not obvious you need quotes.